# Why will a blue torch make a green object appear black?

Tags: visible-light

The color of the bulb at the bottom of a lava lamp can be changed. A special bulb can be put in that changes through the colors, blue green and white. This means in some circumstances, the lava, although green, will appear black. What color bulb will make it appear black?

I know the answer is blue, but when the light is shined against the green liquid, I understand it will be absorbed, but why will it turn black?

Thank

Answer (score 2):

If you shining only blue light on a substance, the green liquid, which absorbs blue light then no light is coming from the green liquid.  Absence of light is blackness.

---

**Update**

One of the best examples of these ideas about colour occurs in nature - green leaves.
The light which hits the leaves is used in photosynthesis.
Many people are under the impression that it is green light which the plant needs for photosynthesis.
That is not so as it is the red and blue light which is needed.
So the leaves absorb all the colours contained in white light absorb the red and the blue ends of the spectrum and re radiate the green leaves.
Hence the leaves are seen to be green.

Here is an absorption spectrum to illustrate this point.

[image]

Comment: But won't it still have green light reflected?

Comment: Where is the green light coming from?

Comment: True. If white light were shone against the green liquid it would appear green still right?

Comment: Remember that no lamp (except lasers) produces spectrally pure colours. The "blue" light will certainly contain other colours as well, including green. Similarly, the liquid will also reflect some other colours besides green. Hence the liquid will still reflect part of the light and will look greenish. The exact colour depends on the "blue" of the light, and the "green" of the liquid.

Comment: @user2108 Your comment showed up as I entered mine. Yes, white light will make green liquid appear green.

Comment: White light contains green light and that light will be absorbed and re emitted as green light.  Other colours will just be absorbed.

Comment: im confused, does this mean yellow objects ALWAYS reflect red and green light, or can they reflect ONLY yellow light, and absorb red and green light. I know there's the color primary theory where all colors consist of red yellow and blue but it seems to contradict how light works, in that there exist pure yellow, pure violet, pure cyan frequencies that do not contain any light in the frequencies of the primaries they would normally be created with on a computer screen.

Comment: @Dmitry Light of wavelength 580nm will excite the red and green cones and not the blue cones and be perceived  as yellow light.  The perception of yellow can also be produced by a broadband spectrum between 550nm and 700nm as long as the green and red cones are comparably stimulated and the blue cones not at all.

Comment: @Farcher I understand, what i am asking is if it's possible for a material to absorb both red and green light but at the same time reflect yellow light.

Comment: @Dmitry It is possible to have a material which absorbs red and green wavelengths which also reflects yellow wavelengths.